# Wordpress naviation menus

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on  wordpress theme developement and navigation menus . But by default the menu items are shown in lists . I want to get menu items as buttons and want to make them dropdowns with bootstrap classes . plz help me

Comment: Can you paste your code here? to see the menu structure?

Comment: wp_nav_menu(array(
                                              'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                              'container' => true,
                                              'fallback_cb' => false
                                            )
                                          );

Answer (score 0):

There easiest way to do this is to use off-the-shelf solution. There is a WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class which extends WordPress' native Walker_Nav_Menu class and makes your Navigation Menus ready for Bootstrap 3. [Download it from GitHub.](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Second, make it available for WordPress. Add following to the functions.php:

```
<?php
require_once('path-to-the-directory/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');
```

Change `path-to-the-directory/` to fit your needs.

Next, alter your `wp_nav_menu()` with the following code:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'header', // match name to yours
    'theme_location'    => 'header',
    'container'         => 'div', // no need to wrap `wp_nav_menu` manually
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'fallback_cb'       => false,
    'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() // Use different Walker
));
```

Note, that you don't need the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">` anymore as it will be added by `wp_nav_menu()` with proper CSS classes and id.

Also, read the WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker README.md file carefully.

originally published here : [Add Bootstrap dropdown class to a nav menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274737/add-bootstrap-dropdown-class-to-a-nav-menu)

Comment: will it make my menu items dropable